# Understanding the Electric Field Strength Tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, metric-tensor, gauge-theory

I am trying to understand the gauge curvature $F_{\mu\nu}$ in electrodynamics, but I have not idea how to derive it. I know from reading my book that $F_{\mu\nu}$ is defined by $D_\mu$ under the relation of $[D_\mu, D_\nu]=ieF_{\mu\nu}$, but I do not fully understand how you get to $F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ through $D_\mu$.

Comment: So what is you question exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that $D_\mu=\partial_\mu-iqA_\mu$. Evaluating the commutator directly on some function $f$:

\begin{align}
[D_\mu,D_\nu]f&=D_\mu D_\nu f-D_\nu D_\mu f\\
&=(\partial_\mu-iqA_\mu)(\partial_\nu-iqA_\nu)f-(\partial_\nu-iqA_\nu)(\partial_\mu-iqA_\mu)f\\
&=\partial_\mu\partial_\nu f-iqA_\mu\partial_\nu f-iq\partial_\mu (A_\nu f)-q^2A_\mu A_\nu f\\&\;\;\;\;-\partial_\nu\partial_\mu f+iqA_\nu\partial_\mu f+iq\partial_\nu (A_\mu f)+q^2A_\nu A_\mu f\\
\end{align}

For any well-behaved function $f$, we have that $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu f = \partial_\nu\partial_\mu f$, so those two terms cancel. In addition, the $A_\mu$ terms commute with each other, so the two $A_\mu A_\nu$ terms cancel. So we're left with:

$$[D_\mu,D_\nu]f=-iqA_\mu\partial_\nu f-iq\partial_\mu (A_\nu f)+iqA_\nu\partial_\mu f+iq\partial_\nu (A_\mu f)$$

Now, note that:

$$\partial_\mu(A_\nu f)=(\partial_\mu A_\nu)f+A_\nu\partial_\mu f$$

by the product rule. Expanding these, we have:

$$[D_\mu,D_\nu]f=-iqA_\mu\partial_\nu f-iq(\partial_\mu A_\nu)f-iqA_\nu\partial_\mu f+iqA_\nu\partial_\mu f+iq(\partial_\nu A_\mu)f+iqA_\mu\partial_\nu f$$

Now four terms cancel, and we have:

$$[D_\mu,D_\nu] f=-iq(\partial_\mu A_\nu)f+iq(\partial_\nu A_\mu)f=-iq(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu)f$$

Since we're no longer doing anything other than multiplying $f$ by constants (all of the derivatives of $f$ vanished in simplifying), we can remove $f$ to obtain the following operator expression:

$$[D_\mu,D_\nu]=-iq(\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu)$$

Setting $q=-e$ gives the expression you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. I understood this.